# How to convert a string into plain ruby code?

Tags: ruby

Here is the string `spec`:

```
  "state :initial_state do
      event :submit, :transitions_to => :acct_init_reviewing
    end
    state :paid
    state :rejected"
```

We need to convert it into plain ruby code inside a `workflow` loop:

```
 workflow do
    state :initial_state do
      event :submit, :transitions_to => :acct_init_reviewing
    end
    state :paid
    state :rejected
 end
```

We tried `eval` without luck:

```
 workflow do
   eval(spec)
 end
```

`eval(spec)` returns `nil`. How to convert a string into plain ruby code for execution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `eval` function returns the result of evaluating your code. That it's `nil` in this case is not surprising, as `state` probably returns nil.

You could just construct the whole thing and evaluate that:

```
eval("workflow { %s }" % code)
```

The `workflow` method might alter the binding on the block given that makes it behave in an unusual way, so expanding the code to include that could help.

It's worth noting that using `eval` to evaluate arbitrary code can be very risky so be absolutely sure that you have control over what's going into this thing.

Comment: Thought about eval the whole thing and it may work. `spec` is by developer and safe. `eval("Workflow::ClassMethods.workflow {%s}" % spec)`  returns `undefined method `workflow' for Workflow::ClassMethods:Module`. If changed to `eval("Workflow::ClassMethods.workflow {%s}" + spec), then it returns `(eval):1: unterminated string meets end of file
(eval):1: syntax error, unexpected end-of-input, expecting '}'
        state :rejected
                       ^`. Not sure what is still missing.

Comment: Calling anything inside of `ClassMethods` directly seems broken and wrong. Shouldn't that be something another class imports with `include`? What context are you calling `workflow` on? You may need to call `eval` with a `binding` option to set the proper context.

Comment: module ClassMethods is inside module Workflow, method is inside module ClassMethods. It is kind of odd. I probably will post for the problem if can't figure it out.

Comment: What's the `%s` for within `{}`?

Comment: That's an easy way of substituting code, but you could also use `#{code}` instead. I just thought seeing `{ #{code} }` would look confusing since the two sets of brackets mean entirely different things.